# Observable from event

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am new to Rx and was going through some samples and came across the below:

```
    Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventHandler, RoutedEventArgs>(
            h => new RoutedEventHandler(h),
            h => Loaded += h,
            h => Loaded -= h)
            .Select(_ => true)
            .StartWith(IsLoaded)
            .Where(l => l)
            .Take(1)
            .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("loaded");
```

I am trying to deconstruct this statement to figure out what it is doing but it is not 100% clear to me.

I understand how **FromEventPattern** is turning the **Loaded** event into an observable sequence. Now, **Select** is going to trigger when **IsLoaded** is true (that is what I am assuming). Is **Select** just getting its info from the RoutedEventArgs?

Now, I am not sure why **StartsWith** is there.  **StartsWith** will prepend a sequence of values to an observable sequence.  So is it just adding the value of **IsLoaded** to the beginning of the list? Wouldn't it already be there after **Select** happens?

**.Where** is not applying any sort of filter so **.Take** will just take the first value of the sequence (which in this case is not used any further).  Then it **Subscribes** and the Console is written to only when the control is loaded.

Is this analysis mostly correct?

Also, any tips on debugging such things (meaning, what the sequence looks like during different stages of the chain)?  I can get info just by attaching the debugger but I was wondering if there are any other tricks/tips that might be commonly used.

Comment: I'm new to Rx too. Based on the usage, I suspect the `Where` isn't necessary.

Comment: For any step in the process, you can manually inject a Do method and output the results to the console (in c++ this is know as printf debugging). You may also want to try out the http://visualrx.codeplex.com/ tool to see what's going on at runtime visually.

Comment: @neontapri, the where would remove a false value if the value of the IsLoaded property was false when the subscription was made as it is in the StartWith operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the Observable operators work the same way the Enumerable operators of the same name.  If you have experience using those, it will be useful here.

So to work through this, let's use an array of integer instead of the observable for a moment.

```
int[] data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

This changes the expression to

```
var results = data.Select(_ => true) 
                  .StartWith(IsLoaded)
                  .Where(l => l)
                  .Take(1);
foreach (var r in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("loaded");
}
```

If you made an array at each stage in the expression you would get:

```
Select - {true, true, true, true}
StartWith - {value of IsLoaded, true, true, true, true}
Where - (if IsLoaded is true)  {true, true, true, true, true}
        (if IsLoaded is false) {true, true, true, true}
Take - {true}
```

With IEnumerables, doing this sort of thing doesn't make much sense because you will always get one value that is true (unless the source array is empty and IsLoaded is false).

The use of this with an IObservable is to make something that will produce one signal when the object is loaded.

- The `StartWith` is provides the signal if the object is already loaded at the time of subscription.
- However, if the object is not loaded, `IsLoaded` will be false, the `Where` will filter it out, and when the event fires, it will trigger a notification.

  - The `Select` will ignore the actual data produced by the event and simply pass a true, which will proceed through the `Where` filter.
- The `Take` is used to only trigger the notification once, regardless of it it comes from the `StartWith`, because the object was already loaded, or the event (via `Select`), when loading completes.

Comment: Spot on. The code in question is simply producing a single value sequence when the object(Control?) is Loaded. If it is already loaded at time of the subscription then a value is pushed immediately, else it will be pushed when it does get loaded.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to Rx, and need some clarity regarding what each operator does, you could try out [Rx Sandbox](http://mnajder.blogspot.in/2010/03/rxsandbox-v1.html) - it uses the old version of Rx, but you could probably learn from v1 before going on to v2. It allows you to visualize and try out combinators on streams, showing you the results as a [marble diagram](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/marble-diagrams).

Here's a representation of the `Zip` operator.

[image: Rx Marble Diagram Viewer]

It's easy to see that it pairs up two values from either stream.

A simple way to debug a sequence would be use the `Do` operator in between, like so:

```
    static IObservable<T> Log<T>(this IObservable<T> stream, string name)
    {
        return stream.Materialize()
                     .Do(n => Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",name, n))
                     .Dematerialize();
    }
```

Example:

```
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
                  .Log("Timer")
                  .Where(i => i % 2 == 0)
                  .Log("Where")
                  .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                  .Log("Sample")
                  .Take(1)
                  .Log("Take")
                  .Subscribe();
```

You can see each value propagating down the pipeline:

```
Timer - OnNext(0)
Where - OnNext(0)
Timer - OnNext(1)
Timer - OnNext(2)
Where - OnNext(2)
Timer - OnNext(3)
Sample - OnNext(2)
Take - OnNext(2)
Take - OnCompleted()
```